# How can I set multiple bootnodes and have them communicate with each other?

Tags: nodes, networking, bootnode, live-network

I would like to know how i can set up multiple bootnodes that share the same state. Would doing this require the bootnodes to share the same database? I know this is basic substrate staff but it would be helpful for a beginner like me to understand how the networking in substrate works. A detailed answer with some examples is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate the key (two ways)

   - Use subkey, and put the key into `<DATA-DIR>/chains/<CHAIN-NAME>/network/<KEY>`
   - Run the node and stop it, the key will be created and it can be found under `<DATA-DIR>/chains/<CHAIN-NAME>/network/<KEY>`
2. Read the your bootnode address

   1. Run the node
   2. Search the output like this

      ```
      [Parachain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/<IP>/tcp/<PORT>/ws/<KEY>
      ```
   3. Replace the `<IP>`with your ip.

   - Note:

     - `<IP>` might be a private address, that you read from the log directly, you need figure out your public ip address and make sure you have a public address
     - if you are running a parachain, only focus on the `[Parachain]` log, not `[Relaychain]`
     - `<PORT>` must be opened, without the firewall
3. Finally, configure the bootnodes like this: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/b2f5f4bb8937028d57bb8ebb5b0cafec6a37bba4/node/src/chain_spec/crab.rs#L270

Tips: backup your key, once you delete the `<DATA-DIR>` the key will be lost, this happens a lot...